# Can I open a non-browser window with Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, window

Can I open a non-browser window with Node.JS? Like the python *tkinter* package.

Comment: You might want to look into [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

Comment: If an answer is helpful enough for you to accept, you should upvote it as well. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Node GUI accomplishes this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodegui/nodegui